# AWS Greengrass daemon write pipe: broken pipe error

Tags: pi-3

I am trying to install AWS Greengrass in my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. I am following this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/userguide/start-core.html). But while starting the service I am getting the following error

```
sudo /greengrass/greengrassd start
Setting up greengrass daemon
Validating execution environment
Found cgroup subsystem: cpu
Found cgroup subsystem: cpuacct
Found cgroup subsystem: blkio
Found cgroup subsystem: memory
Found cgroup subsystem: devices
Found cgroup subsystem: freezer
Found cgroup subsystem: net_cls

Starting greengrass daemon.....
Greengrass daemon 1364 failed to start
write pipe: broken pipe
```

Please suggest the resolution

Comment: Have you created `ggc_user` and `ggc_group` as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/userguide/prepare-raspi.html)?

Comment: I did it previously, but still faced the same issue. Nevertheless I did a fresh install and for some strange reason, this time it worked out fine. Still I would request you to give an insight, why you thought this might be the reason.

Comment: Sorry, I have no insight to share, I just took a wild guess. I'm glad it worked out for you though.